# Как сохранить данные из программы (текст) в кэш память или куда то в скрытую папку (android)

Tags: c++, файлы, c++builder, кэширование, radstudio

radstudio c++builder; разработка под андроид;

Мне нужно сохранить данные из программы (тест, вычисления) в программе под андроид.

```
 lbxsett->Items->SaveToFile("/sdcard/settings.txt");
```

Вот как я сохранял. Так сохраняет просто на внутреннюю память, как сделать чтоб файлы нельзя было редактировать, изменять вне программы? как нибудь в скрытую папку можно сохранить? или в кэш программы?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел правильный способ, делюсь:

1) добавляем библиотеку

```
#include  <System.IOUtils.hpp>
```

на .cpp форму.

2)

```
Memo1->Lines->SaveToFile(GetHomePath()+"test.txt");
```

3) перфект!

Comment: Рассмешили, право. Даже не на рутованом любой corebot даст возможность чего-то с ними сделать. Или `adb`.